# How to obtain the input the user entered in a 'Input" tag in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am currently trying to develop a react-native application and so far it is very basic with a few input tags and a button. My problem is that I am unaware of how to actually take the input the user entered within these input tags and use them. I have tried using onChangeText but I was unable to find a solution, below is my code. Any help is Greatly Appreciated!

```
return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Academic Assistant</Text>
        <Input
          ref={time}
          placeholder='Time Studying'
          containerStyle={styles.inputBox}
        />
        <Input
          placeholder='Amount of Assignments'
          containerStyle={styles.inputBox}
        />
        <Button style={styles.button}
          title="Submit"
          onPress={ShowData}
      />
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
  );
```

All the code before is just the proper syntax for the beginning of a react-native app and the importing of different modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need state [about state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html). [about hook useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

1. Add state: (import React, {useState} from 'react')

```
const [time, setTime] = useState('')
const [amount, setAmout] = useState('')
```

2. Add value and onChange event to input

```
<Input
   value={time}
   onChange={(e) => setTime(e.target.value)}
/>
...
<Input
   value={amount}
   onChange={(e) => setAmount(e.target.value)}
/>
```

3. Use state to manipulate data. For example, you can display data from state to the screen:

```
return (
   ...
   {time} // time input
   {amount} // amount input
   ...
)
```